# Why does a single pointer act like an array and the dereference operator (*) isn´t needed to access the pointed element?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

```
int *insertZeroPosition(int *pf,int n,int k){
    int *ptr=(int *)calloc(n+1,sizeof(int));
    int i;
    ptr[0]=k;
    for (i=1;i<n+1;i++,pf++){
        ptr[i]=*pf; 
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Why is it `ptr[i]=*pf` instead of `*ptr[i]=*pf` even though ptr is a pointer?

Comment: What is a _pointerunction_?

Comment: `ptr[x]` is equivalent to `*(ptr+x)`. This is really a basic syntax question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)

Comment: I'm sorry about the word  'pointerunction'. It is a typing error. I meant to say pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why this is equivalent? I´ve thought with `ptr[x]` you address the value of a certain pointer of a pointer array (which is the address stored inside that pointer variable) and with `*(ptr+x)` the value this pointer points to.

Comment: Because `ptr[i]` is *exactly* the same as `*(ptr+i)`, you can also say `i[ptr]` and kind of freak people out :-)

Comment: @SteveFriedl Why it is the exact same? I´ve thought with `ptr[i]` you address the value of a certain pointer of a pointer array (which is the address stored inside that pointer variable) and with `*(ptr+i)` the value this pointer points to.

Comment: `ptr` is not "pointer array". It is a pointer. Anyway, you have a standard quote down there.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica they are the same because the language says so.   Arrays are not first-class data types in C - though they are in other languages - and I'm not sure how to explain it more than that. C *defined* array access notation in terms of derference-pointer plus index.  Now it's true that `ptr[i]` and `(ptr + i)` are not the same thing - the first accesses the element at the array, while the second only computes the address, but adding the deference `*(ptr + i)` accesses the element.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Ok, i understand now what the clue is, so that it works for one-single pointer. But what if we would talk about as `ptr` as an array of pointers, then the expression `ptr[i]` should access the value of one pointer inside the pointer array and not the value pointed to by the first pointer, isn´t it? Does this "rule" only works for single pointers?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica Pointers don't generally know if they point to a single item or an array of them, so if you have `int **ptr` then `ptr` is a pointer to a pointer, `ptr[0]` is a pointer and `ptr[0][0]` is an int.  You can't tell from here if either of the pointers points to just one of a thing or more than one of a thing.  But `p[1][3]` is exactly the same as `*(*(p + 1) + 3)`

Comment: please don't downvote this question just because it is a matter of simple syntax. this is a valid question for stackoverflow, with a valid answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `p[i]` is equivalent to `*((p) + (i))`. The dereference is still there, even with the array-subscript syntax.

C Standard, § 6.5.2.1.2:

> The definition of the subscript operator []
> is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

You can rewrite the code to say `*(ptr + i) = *pf` if you want; there's no difference.